# Horizontal alignment of multiple images

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

[image]

In the current scenario, the images are arranged in a vertical sense, however I wanted to align the subfigures in a horizontal sense. This is the code that I'm using. Also I'm working on a template, which follows IEEE convention.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth,height=5cm]{MobileApp/login.png}
\caption{Login Screen}
\label{fig:login screen}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth,height=5cm]{MobileApp/Selectcanteen.png}
\caption{Select Canteen Screen}
\label{fig:Select canteen screen}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Caption for this figure with two images}
\label{fig:image2}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I didn't see this question before. I suggest you use `0.5\columnwidth` instead of `0.25\textwidth` because the `\textwidth` does not take the column separation into account, so when you add the `%` at the end of `\end{subfigure}` your pictures will overflow the margin (and you'll get a `Overfull \hbox` warning).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Ya, this problem too got solved by adding just a % at the end. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Though this one also has the `%` problem, I marked with a differen duplicate about the difference of `\textwidth` and `\columnwidth` (and other `\...width`s :)

Comment: Nice :) Actually had a confusion with those terms too :P